# Tried to log in into a public network and devices got screwed

Tags: boot

I have Ubuntu 18 LTS installed into a device and everything was running smoothly until I tried to log in into a public network, a McDonalds. On next startup Grub appeared even thought I have configured it to not appear on startup and when trying to load the OS, I get redirected to initramfs console unable to run any commands. Now the device is heavily customized and I'd hate to do a clean install. I also had Timeshift installed and kept a regular database of images but I am unable to access any packet and load an image. Any advice? I am able to provide as much information as you request based on my current restricted access to the device. 
Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: We would need to see the exact error you're seeing.

Comment: Grub loads and after choosing Ubuntu, I get a black screen with the following. /dev/nvme0n1p2 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/nvme0n1p2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/nvme0n1p2 requires a manual fsck

And then cursor stops at:
(initramfs)_

Comment: You need to boot to a liveUSB or similar and run `fsck` against your disk, since it sounds like there's some problems with the filesystem.

Comment: And probably nothing related to the use of WiFi of that distasteful junk food joint. It look like a typical Galaxy of after this, because of this.

Comment: I thought it might not be related but I thought I might mention it since I caught a glimpse of an SSH command running past when it boots. I will try running fsck with a live USB, however I have no idea how this happened, I literary did nothing else other than reboot the device :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the `initramfs` prompt, type `fsck -f /`. Repeat if there are errors. Then type `exit`, and reboot the computer.

If that doesn't work for you, we'll do it the old-fashioned way...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: None of the two methods worked unfortunately.

Comment: Scratch last post. Can't edit cause of 5 mins passed. It worked perfectly I was just not doing sudo fsck -f to the correct partition. 
Thank you very much sir, really helpful.